# expand Widget in pyqt

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I am trying to force my `QTextEdit` widget to span the whole cell of the `QGridLayout`.
I tried a lot of different combinations of `QSizePolicy` and `sizeHint()`, but nothing has the desired effect.

In the example below I have a main widget of minimum size 800x600 and another widget 'blue' of size 100x100 in column 1. So I want the `QTextEdit` in column 0 to be 700x600.

In general I want 'edit' to be (n-`blue.width()`)xm if my main widget is resized to nxm.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    mainWidget.setMinimumSize(800, 600)
    mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(mainWidget)

    blue = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWidget)
    blue.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue')
    blue.setFixedSize(100, 100)
    edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(mainWidget)

    ### what to do here?
    policy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    edit.setSizePolicy(policy)
    ###

    mainLayout.addWidget(edit, 0, 0, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    mainLayout.addWidget(blue, 0, 1, 1, 1, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    mainLayout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
    mainLayout.setColumnStretch(1, 0)

    mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)
    mainWidget.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just placing too many constraints on the `QGridLayout`.  Try adding the widgets to the layout with just...

```
mainLayout.addWidget(edit, 0, 0)
mainLayout.addWidget(blue, 0, 1)
```

Also, you probably don't need to set the sizing policy explicitly -- it should just work *as-is* (it does for me).

The full, minimal working example would be something like...

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore

if __name__ == '__main__':
    qApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    mainWidget.setMinimumSize(800, 600)
    mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(mainWidget)

    blue = QtWidgets.QWidget(mainWidget)
    blue.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue')
    blue.setFixedSize(100, 100)
    edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(mainWidget)

    mainLayout.addWidget(edit, 0, 0)
    mainLayout.addWidget(blue, 0, 1)

    mainWidget.show()
    sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a reason for this? my understanding is that the alignment and the size policy are independant? in this example the alignment is of course unneccessary..